# Javascript array of key pair objects to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have this array of objects:

```
0:key:"name" value:"John"
1:key:"age" value:"30"
2:key:"car" value:"Ford"
```

How can I turn it into this:

```
[{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":"ford" }]
```

I was trying something like this:

```
tempArray.forEach(function(s) {
    var object = {
        s.key: s.value
    }

    newArray.push(object);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce()`

```js
var arr = [{key:"name", value:"John"},
{key:"age", value:"30"},
{key:"car" ,value:"Ford"}];

var result = [];
var map = arr.reduce((a,curr)=>{
  a[curr.key] = curr.value;
  return a;
},{});
result.push(map);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

i hope it will help you

```
    var a = [{name:"a"},{age:10},{car:"ford"}];

var d={};
a.map((data)=>{

  if(data.name){
    d.name=data.name;
  }else if(data.age){
    d.age=data.age
  }else{
    d.car=data.car
  }

})

  console.log(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for a single key/value pair and collenct all into an object with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
var array = [{ key: "name", value: "John" }, { key: "age", value: "30" }, { key: "car", value: "Ford"}],
    object = Object.assign(...array.map(({ key, value }) => ({ [key]: value })));
    
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array = [{ key: "name", value: "John" }, { key: "age", value: "30" }, { key: "car", value: "Ford"}];

let answer = [array.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.key] = cur.value
  return acc
},{})]

console.log(answer)
```

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to loop thru the array and creating them on the fly